# how can I access the following?

Tags: ios

```
class GroupEntities: NSObject {
    var name = String()
    var noOfMembers = Int()
    var isAdmin = Bool()
    var isOpen = Bool()
}
```

in `GroupEntities` class, how can i access this in the `UITableview` of another class by name called `RJContactGroup`

Comment: You need to read some basic book about the development. In model class you should not access view class (read about MVC pattern). Instead, in your `UIViewController` class you should access both `GroupEntities`  object as well as your `UITableView` object.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
class GroupEntities: NSObject {
    var name = String()
    var noOfMembers = Int()
    var isAdmin = Bool()
    var isOpen = Bool()
}


class MyTableViewController {
    var rjContactGroup = GroupEntities()

    func setProperties() {
       rjContactGroup.name = "Test Name"
       rjContactGroup.noOfMembers = 6
       rjContactGroup.isAdmin = true
       rjContactGroup.isOpen = true
   }
}
```